# How do I disconnect a Bluetooth device?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, bluetooth, disconnect

I have a device actively connected to the computer via Bluetooth. From my C#.NET application I wish to disconnect the device so that the computer is no longer connected to the device.

How would I go about doing this?

I'm guess it would have something to do with finding the appropriate Socket and disconnecting that socket? (But this is purely venturing a guess as I know nothing about Socket connections.)

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no Bluetooth support in .NET.  I recommend a hammer.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with Bluetooth (Java and Perl, not c# specifically), the connection begins to tear down when you close the input/output streams. Then the final dose of poison is to close the socket. 
/$0.02

Answer (score -1):

From a MSDN blog on [Bluetooth Device Development using C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/codejunkie/bluetooth-device-development-using-c):

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Text;
  using Microsoft.WindowsMobile.SharedSource.Bluetooth;
     
  namespace ToggleBluetooth
   {
     class Program
       {
          static void Main(string[] args)
         {
              BluetoothRadio brad = new BluetoothRadio();
              if (brad.BluetoothRadioMode == BluetoothRadioMode.Off)
                  brad.BluetoothRadioMode = BluetoothRadioMode.On;
               else
                brad.BluetoothRadioMode = BluetoothRadioMode.Off;
          }
     }
   }
```

Comment: Believe that's for Windows Mobile, I am looking for Windows Desktop.

Thanks.